# Python function to insert data with SQL query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm getting the below error, although SQL syntax seems right. Please help.

```
def create_table(self, **kwargs):
    query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ("
    comma = r', '
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key != 'table_name':
            query = query + key + ' ' + value + comma
    query = query.format(kwargs['table_name']).rstrip(' ,') + ")"
    print(query)
    return self.cursor.execute(query)

def insert_values(self, *args):
    query = r"INSERT INTO {} VALUES ("
    comma = r','
    for arg in args:
        if arg != args[0]:
            if type(arg) == str:
                query = query + "'" + arg + "'" + comma
            else:
                query = query + str(arg) + comma
    query = query.format(args[0]).rstrip(" ,") + ")"
    print(query)
    return self.cursor.execute(query)

db.create_table(table_name='store', item='TEXT', quantity='INTEGER', price='REAL')
db.insert_values('store', 'wine glass', 8, 10.5)
```

Output

```
# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)

# INSERT INTO store VALUES ('wine glass',8,10.5)
```

> sqlite3.OperationalError: table store has 1 columns but 3 values were
>   supplied

Comment: Be sure to `commit` any actions or set `autocommit=True`.

Comment: Is this the full code ? The error message is rather clear. Is it possible that the table `store` already exists, and has only one column ? Then the first statement `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` will run without error and do nothing since the table already exists.

Answer (score -1):

## Solved

Parfait you were somehow right.
I deleted the local databse my class was making every time I runned the code, and restarted every action. Methods are working, I just wasn't seeing actual result.

full code here:
https://github.com/BackstageBones/Python-Object-Oriented-Programming/blob/tkinter_app/Desktop%20Database%20Application/database.py